# Кто такой Бармалей?

Tags: этимология, ономастика, литература

Вопрос детский, но все-таки.
Все мы знаем персонажа "Доктора Айболита" Чуковского - Бармалея. Отрицательный герой, злодей, разбойник и прочая, и прочая. Но вот интересно было бы узнать, как появилось это имя? Все имена там понятны: Айболит, Тянитолкай, Авва. А вот Бармалей выглядит как просто набор букв. Так и есть, или имя тоже образовано от какого-то слова?

*А еще всегда озадачивает, почему в детских поликлиниках рисуют Айболита, если он ветеринар?)))))*

Comment: Айболит детей спасал.

Comment: Эм... он зверей спасал прежде всего)))

Comment: Нет, прежде всего он спасал именно от детей. Первое произведение как раз о том, как Айболит выручил их от Бармалея.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Чуковского персонаж с этим именем появился из рассуждений о названии Бармалеевой улицы с художником Добужинским. Тот в шутку высказал идею, что был такой разбойник Бармалей и набросал рисунок с его изображением. Относительно самого названия улицы в Петербурге есть несколько гипотез.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бармалеева_улица

Comment: Кстати, тогда интересно происхождение фамилии Бармалеев, в честь которого названа улица

Answer (score 2):

Насчет ветеринара. Так и дети весьма доброжелательно относятся к уподоблению себя всяким зайкам и котикам.

. . .

Вот касательно Бармалея. Да, Чуковскому приписывают изобретения "Бармалея" по Бармалеевой улице Петербурга. Сам Чуковский о том вроде никогда не говорил. Может, считал очевидным, а может наоборот, хранил тайну названия. Чуковский, как коренной питерец, конечно, не мог не знать о существовании той улицы, но он мог знать и еще кое-что, какое-то имя собственное, а то и нарицательное, не имеющее отношения к (гипотетическому?) персонажу, давшему имя улице, но созвучное с ним.

Больно уж оно похоже то ли на "Эдигей", то ли на "поскорей"... А может "Брадобрей"? Или "пожалей"? Подобные клички, кстати, любили давать охотничьим собакам. А от охоты на зверюшек уже и до звериного разбойника Бармалея недалеко... Выбор Чуковского явно не случаен.

Comment: @irinaGLA. До того, как прочёл ваш и @Alex_ander`а комментарии, мне всегда казалось, что БАРМАЛЕЙ это мусульманский БАЙРАМ-АЛИ. Помимо сдвоенного имени, в Туркмении есть и город с таким названием.

Comment: Откуда в Питере Байрам-Али? Другое дело, что фамилия Бармалеев могла как-то быть образована от него. Но версия с шотладцем Бромлеем уж никак не хуже.

Comment: @behemothus. Ну , я же пояснил : "до того , как прочёл..." . Теперь я знаю , что это от названия питерской улицы !

Answer (score 0):

> Кстати, тогда интересно происхождение фамилии Бармалеев, в честь которого названа улица

Так по ссылке есть. Насчет "в честь" это не совсем верно. Основная версия сводится к тому, что это обычный домовладелец, никакой иной чести не снискавший.
Кстати, помнится, обсуждалось здесь году еще в 2012-м... Могу путать, может и не здесь... Попробую найти.

> все имена там понятны: Айболит, Тянитолкай, Авва.

А Бибигон? Он, правда, "не там"...
Да и Авва - тоже не подарок.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте смотреть фактам в лицо. Бармалей - только на словах грозный и страшный разбойник. На самом деле трагический персонаж, которого проглотил крокодил. В конце сказки, переродившийся в добряка:" И уеду в Ленинград, буду там печь пирожки и раздавать их детям". Фактически Бармалей - контрабандист (зверей), а не людоед и убийца. Теперь о Бармалеев(е). В начале 18 века появляется прообраз общежития - коммунальное жильё. См. Бролей. Бромлей. Коммуна (социологический термин). Добавлю от себя ещё одну цитату: Одна летопись, считая имя Ермака прозвищем, дает ему христианское имя Василия. По мнению иркутского историка А. Г. Сутормина, полностью имя Ермака якобы звучало как Василий Тимофеевич Аленин. Эта же версия фамилии Ермака обыгрывается в сказе П. П. Бажова «Ермаковы лебеди». Одна из версий происхождения имени Ермака относится к казачьему быту, поскольку у казаков слово «аРМак» означает большой, ОБЩИЙ на всех котёл. Фамилия Ермака достоверно не установлена.  Вот такие пирожки.

Comment: А при чем тут Ермак?!

Версия прямого производства Бармалея от Бромлея отвергается исследователями.
Да, еще. Вроде он там пряники обежал раздавать, а не пирожками торговать. ПочуЙствуйте разницу.

Comment: АРМАк общий котёл. И писал я не о Бромлее, а об совпадении в разных языках одного и того же значения. Господин @бегемотус - читайте внимательнее, раздавать кренделя и пироги это не то же самое, что торговать пирожками. И, пожалуйста, если вам нечего сказать, не придирайтесь к мелочам. И да. Имейте совесть - пишите грамотно.

Comment: @Бывалый. Ермак тут действительно НЕ ПРИ ЧЁМ! Но, уж коли затронули имя покорителя Сибири, то поясню: среди казаков было много евреев - потомков хазар, и многие казаки имели два имени - крестильное и семейное. Ермак - это еврейское имя. Точно также Стенька/Степан Разин. Где кто-нибудь сталкивался, чтобы Степанов уменьшительно называли Стеньками? Семейное имя Стенек (=Стенька), а крестильное - Степан. То же самое гетман Богдан Хмельницкий. Если точно, то он именуется, как Богдан-Зиновий Хмельницкий. Все думают, что Богдан это богом+дан, а это еврейское имя, - могу доказать.

Comment: ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ВЫШЕПОМЕЩЁННОМУ. Тема еврейского казачества это очень большая тема, которая просто не влезет в комментарий. Кому интересно, зайдите хотя бы по этой ссылочке: http://www.jewage.org/wiki/ru/article:Еврейские_казаки  и вот по этой: http://istclub.ru/index.php?showtopic=1082  . /Последняя публикация - мой собственный материал, но под другим ником. / И этими двумя ссылками тема еврейского казачества не исчерпывается.

Comment: Я не все. Я сам по себе. И Ермак тут действительно не при чём. И даже скорей всего вы меня убедите. Всё уже было, не раз.